# Duplicated rows in MS Access database

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates

MS Access database was corrupted and in one table few rows was duplicated. They are **absolutely** same and there isn't any unique field between duplicates, even primary keys. Because of this, primary key was reseted from this table after repairing database.
Now I can only know rows that were duplicated:

```
select * from tablename
where id in(
select id from tablename
group by id
having count (*) > 1)
```

To designate primary key I must delete one of two duplicates, but don't know how.

Comment: search SO: asked a gazillion times before. GBN had a good answer I seem to recall...

Comment: I saw this question, but as I understand it, there was a unique identifier different for each duplicate. In my case there is no such field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this is with a temporary table:

```
select distinct t.*
into TempTABLE
from tablename t;

delete from tablename;

insert into tablename
    select *
    from TempTable;
```

That is, remove the duplicates using `distinct`.  Delete all the rows from the original table, and then insert the unique rows.